# installing django on windows

Tags: python, windows, django, apache, unix

I am having a bit of a time installing django on my local machine due to the fact that my local machine is windows. One thing I am having issues with is the includes

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Every file has this inlclude. I set python in my global varibles so I can call on it like

```
python
```

or I can include it like

```
#!python
```

but not like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

my assumption is that in order for this to work. I probably might have to move my interpreter to a folder called

```
c:/user/bin/env
```

Is this the case or is there a better way. I damn for sure dont want to change all the paths in all the folders.

Comment: That line (the shebang) is used by bash and some other unix shells to determine what executable to run it against.  It's not relevant in Windows

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set PATH environment variable (add path to python) and leave django files as them are.

Comment: ok, I am new to python. could you elaborate more. add path to python ?? I added python path to window, but not the other way around. how does this work and is actually happening when I do this. This seems like a reasonable solution thanks

Comment: My Computer - Properties - Advanced - Environment Variables. In PATH variable add path to your python installation (c:\dev\python) in my case.

Comment: I am pretty sure its already in the environment variables. If I go to my command and type in 'python'. It fires right up.

Comment: Then you just need to download official release 9http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#installing-official-release) and run 'python setup.py install'

Comment: Also be sure that you have a system environment variable as follows: PYTHONPATH=c:\your-install-directory-for-python;c:\your-install-directory-for-python\Scripts